# Can i use 8 gauge wire with 10 gauge ground with double 50 amp breaker

Tags: electrical, wiring

So i bought 8 gauge 3 wire for my stove but after installing i seen it was 10 gauge ground wire with the wite and black being 8 gauge. Will it make a difference?

Comment: What *type* of 8/3 cable did you buy? NM? UF? AC? MC?

Comment: I was wondering if anyone would catch that.  Typical 8ga cable is only good for 40 amps.  I know some types can go higher, but we need to know the type.  Also, why no neutral?

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I think the OP means 2-wire plus ground, so white is neutral (USA color code)

Comment: Nathan,  GeorgeA  raises a point:  are you trying to bring 3-phase 240 to the stove, or just  single-phase AC?  You can't use this 2-wire material for 3phase AC

Comment: It would really help if people that post questions of this nature what country they are in. Given that the OP here mentioned a double pole  50 amp breaker, I assumed USA, but could be wrong.

Answer (score 5):

### You can't use #8 on a 50A circuit

You have to read out of the 60C column of 310.15(B)(16), which means you are limited to 40A.

It would be possible with other classes of wire in conduit,  but not possible with the usual types of cable used in America used for this job (which is what you are referring to).

If you really need 50A, then change to #6 cable.

### But the ground is fine

Circuits up to 60A are able to use a 10 AWG ground.

The conductors need to carry current continuously.  The ground only needs to carry current long enough to trip the breaker.

Comment: Note that the limitation you talk about is only a thing for NM and UF at these sizes; SER, AC, and MC are not so limited